# Facebook authentication - are there different approaches?

Tags: python, django, facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm in process of building an app for Facebook using Python and Django. I'm investigating different solutions for integration with Facebook authentication API.

So far I've found the two viable solutions:

- [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)
- [python-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk)

I've already tried the first one and it seems to work nicely. I've just read about the second one and it seems to use Facebook JavaScript SDK.

My question is: are those two libraries doing authentication differently? Do I understand correctly that the first one uses OAuth directly to communicate with Facebook and get an authentication token from there, whereas the second one just displays some JavaScript enriched intermediate sites that request the authentication token from the level of a web browser?

In general: are there different ways of going about facebook authentication (JavaScript SDK vs something else)? Why is JavaScript SDK a recommended approach? And is the "something else" approach incapable of producing cookies and therefore less efficient in any way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a backend implementation (python, PHP, Perl, etc), you generally have to use URL redirects (Graph API) to interact with Facebook and the user. Personally, I don't think this is a good user experience.

Using the javascript SDK, you can do everything inline. Which means the user never has to leave your page to grant permissions, post to wall, send requests, etc. You can still use the backend libs to do other things. And you would need to if you are doing any "offline" activity or subscribing to real time events.

In the end, you end up with the same authorization rights. Both are making similar calls to Facebook to get a valid, authorized session. So either one, or both works.

Comment: For any nontrivial application, you'll probably end up setting both.

Comment: @Filip Do you mean both approaches? Why is that - could you explain how the flow goes? I read fb docs a few times and I find them really confusing. They are very technical and don't really explain the idea behind it all.

Comment: @julkiewicz, yeah, using both approaches is the better way to describe it. Like Brent said, with the JS SDK FB will handle the user on your behalf and properly manage cookies which will get pushed to your application with each request. Now, with the authorization details for the user from the cookie, in your backend you can then communicate directly with the Graph API, such as performing queries with the user (get the users friends, set the users status message, etc.) and persist any relevant details in the database.

Comment: @Filip Ah, ok. So you meant two approaches: Graph API for aquiring the data and JS SDK for authentication - sure, I agree.